# Error When Parsing Data: Undefined variable: mystudents

Tags: php, laravel, parsing

I do parsing data from my command, before this, it gets that data. When I want to do it again, it becomes an error.

I got:

```
 Undefined variable: mystudents (View: /home/john/Documents/api4/api4/resources/views/emails/welcome.blade.php)`enter code here`
```

this is my code on  command:

```
  foreach ($student as $mystudent) {

        $user = User::find($mystudent->user_id);
       Mail::to($user)->send(new WelcomeMail($mystudent));
   }
    
 
    Mail::to($user)->send(new WelcomeMail($student));
    echo "check email";
```

this is my code on view

```
@foreach ($mystudents as $student)
        
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $student->student_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->phone }}</td>
```

I'm not sure that my code was correct. Hopefully, you help me, sir.

Comment: We need to see the code of your WelcomeMail - is there a `mystudents` variable defined?

Comment: Yeah, I got this, that my blade does not write based on my WelcomeMail

Answer (score 1):

You are running a `foreach` loop in your command, as well as in your view.

Also, you are calling the Mail `send` method two times.

I think you only need a foreach once, in your command:

```
foreach ($student as $mystudent) {
    $user = User::find($mystudent->user_id);
    Mail::to($user)->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
}
```

The code in your view can be something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $user->student_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->phone }}</td>
</tr>
```